# how to get more torrents to seed in biglybt

Tags: bittorrent

I have been trying to have few private torrents to seed as default but I dunno what the problem with bigblybt, I am unable to get most of them to seed, even if they don't seed anything. They all show up as queued. Can anybody help me get them seeding instead of queing them. The options are confusing as shown in the screeenshot below.

[image: bigblybt options screen]

Looking forward to some tips which will make the process smoother.

Answer (score 0):

BiglyBT will queue torrents according to the settings under 'Queue'. For example, if a torrent has no peers to seed to (reported from trackers or DHT) then there is probably no point in it being in an active 'Seeding' state and using resources. Check out the old Vuze documentation as things haven't changed much - https://wiki.vuze.com/w/Seeding_Rules

You can always 'force start' a torrent by right-clicking on it and selecting that option (you need to set your Mode > beginner to see this option). This will cause the torrent to be permanently active. However this causes BiglyBT to continuously consume some resources and if you have a lot of active torrents it adds up.